# Text Wrapping and web-kit-line-clamp discrepancy between Anchor Tag and Button in Fixed-width container

Tags: html, css

I'm facing a problem where extended text without spaces inside an anchor tag wraps around a container with a fixed width, overflow-wrap: break-word and web-kit-line-clamp. Strangely, when I place a button in the same container, the text does not wrap, and web-kit-line-clamp fails to take effect. Although using overflow-wrap: anywhere resolves the wrapping issue for text inside the button, the web-kit-line-clamp is still ineffective. What might be causing this inconsistency?

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1FpJ.png)

I'm attaching fiddle for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/frontenddev_sumanth/rse1v6mp/6/

```css
.action-container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-wrap: wrap;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  width: 150px;
}

.btn-1 {
  display: inline;
  /*   display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 5; */
  background: white;
  border: none;
}

.btn-2 {
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
  display: inline;
  background: white;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<p>
  With overflow-wrap: break-word, for text inside Anchor tag text-wrapping: YES and text-ellipsis: YES
</p>
<div class="action-container">
  <a>
         ThisisalongtextholdbythecontainerThisisalongtextholdbythecontainerThisisalongtextholdbythecontainerThisisalongtextholdbythecontainerThisisalongtextholdbythecontainerThisisalongtextholdbythecontainer
         </a>
</div>
<p>
  With overflow-wrap: break-word,for text inside button text-wrapping: NO and text-ellipsis: NO
</p>
<div class="action-container">
  <button class="btn-1">
         ThisisalongtextholdbythecontainerThisisalongtextholdbythecontainerThisisalongtextholdbythecontainerThisisalongtextholdbythecontainerThisisalongtextholdbythecontainerThisisalongtextholdbythecontainer.
         </button>
</div>
<p>
  With overflow-wrap: anywhere, for text inside button text-wrapping: YES and text-ellipsis: NO
</p>
<div class="action-container">
  <button class="btn-2">
         ThisisalongtextholdbythecontainerThisisalongtextholdbythecontainerThisisalongtextholdbythecontainerThisisalongtextholdbythecontainerThisisalongtextholdbythecontainerThisisalongtextholdbythecontainer
         </button>
</div>
```